# problem making a urdf file in ros

Tags: ros, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All ! I am new to ROS. I want to make a urdf  model of a robot  and I started urdf tutorials available at
I have installed ROS in my PC. when i just try to run my first command in above tutorials it does not work. terminal response is below. Please help.

abc@jkdl:~/ROS/URDF Tutorials$ rosmake urdfdom_model
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['urdfdom_model']                                                             
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/javi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130905-132619                           
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['urdfdom_model'] to:
[]                                                                
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['urdfdom_model']              
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.                                
abc@jkdl:~/ROS/URDF Tutorials$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76612/problem-making-a-urdf-file-in-ros/) by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luca](https://answers.ros.org/users/564/luca/) on 2013-09-05**:
It would be helpful if you provide the link the the tutorial. I suppose it is the one accessible  http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are new to ROS I assume you did not compile ROS from source. This means you can skip the rosmake step and try

> rosrun urdfdom check_urdf my_robot.urdf

I am guessing you installed groovy?

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0